# Python - How to make range queries in Azure Table Storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage

I am stuck trying to find the right syntax for creating a range query from python to an Azure Table Storage table.

The continuation token cannot help me since I want to define a specific range or RowKeys and retrieve only those.

I have been trying the following

```
rows = table_service.query_entities(
    tableName,
    "PartitionKey eq '6' and RowKey gt '1452702466022' and RowKey lt '1452702466422")
```

and

```
rows = table_service.query_entities(
    'rawpowervalues6', "PartitionKey eq '6'",
    select="RowKey gt '1452702466022' and RowKey lt '1452702466422")
```

With no luck. I cannot find any official documentation regarding python range queries. The best resource so far for that matter is [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160524/date-range-queries-in-azure-table-storage) but I cannot make it work in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first query, you are missing an ending quote: `'`. You might want to try:

```
rows = table_service.query_entities( \
    tableName, \
    "((PartitionKey eq '6' and RowKey gt '1452702466022') and RowKey lt '1452702466422')")
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding, @minghan said was correct that your first code is right but missing an end-quote `'` in the `filter` argument. For the second code, the `select` argument only select property name for the return entities, but do not code the condition expression like `filter` in it.

You can review the definition of the function `table_service.query_entites` below from Github https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/table/tableservice.py, and combine with the section `Supported Comparison Operators` of the reference doc [Querying Tables and Entities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd894031.aspx)

```
def query_entities(self, table_name, filter=None, select=None, top=None,
               next_partition_key=None, next_row_key=None):
    '''
    Get entities in a table; includes the $filter and $select options.
    table_name:
        Table to query.
    filter:
        Optional. Filter as described at
        http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd894031.aspx
    select:
        Optional. Property names to select from the entities.
    top:
        Optional. Maximum number of entities to return.
    next_partition_key:
        Optional. When top is used, the next partition key is stored in
        result.x_ms_continuation['NextPartitionKey']
    next_row_key:
        Optional. When top is used, the next partition key is stored in
        result.x_ms_continuation['NextRowKey']
    '''
```